# Condition in a theorem of Hall

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

There is a well-celebrated theorem of Hall, which characterizes solvable groups according to the existence of Hall-$\pi$ subgroups. In this theorem, I was wondering whether it can be stated in a little modified way. Thus, my question boils at the following.

Let $G$ be a finite group. I am concerning about whether the following properties equivalent (i.e. is it true that $G$ satisfied one property if and only if it satisfies the other)?

> (P1) Whenever $|G|=p^nm$, $p\nmid m$, then $G$ contains subgroups of order $p^n$ as well as $m$.
>
> (P2) Whenever $|G|=rs$ with $(r,s)=1$, then $G$ has subgroup of order $r$ and $s$.

Obviously, (P2) implies (P1). Is it true that (P1) implies (P2) without using Hall's theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, (P1) implies (P2). You can find Hall subgroups of all orders by taking intersections of the largest Hall subgroups, which (P1) assumes exist.

For example, if $|G|=p^nm=q^rs$ with $p$ and $q$ distinct primes, and $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of orders $m$ and $s$, then since $|HK| \le |G|$, we get $|H \cap K| \ge m/q^r = s/p^n$. But $|H \cap K|$ is not divisible by $p$ or $q$, so  we must equality there, and hence $H \cap K$ is a Hall $\pi(G) \setminus \{p,q\}$ subgroup.

You can then construct Hall subgroups of smaller orders by intersecting existing ones with the largest ones.